Should I use a stepper or wizard for a form that is frequently used by users?
I have a form that consist of 5 main question, of which 4 are not necessary to answer depending on the selection on the first. So the flow is roughly:

Are you allowed to swim?
yes -> go to 2
no -> finished
no, it is forbidden from / to -> enter date -> go to 2 or finished

Are you allowed to wear a wetsuit?
yes -> go to 3 or finished
no -> go to 3 or finished
no, it is forbidden from / to -> enter data -> go to 3 or finished

Are any of this items forbidden to bring along?
snorkel -> yes/no
fins -> yes/no
[...]
make any selection then go to 4. or finished

Are there any things you should be extra carefull about?
water is extra salty -> yes/no
tides are huge -> yes/no
[...]
make any selection then go to 5. or finished

Are there any dangers you should know about?
sharks -> yes/no
pirates -> yes/no
[...]
make any selection then finished


Because users might fill out this form 20 times in a row, I would be adverse to using a classical wizard component. Also some users might just fill out point 5., because the only relevant information here is to be alert about sharks.
Question 4 for example realistically has ~20 items that can be checked, so I don't want to show all of it by default.
Would you consider a structure with all 5 main question visible and an yes/no toggle on the right as default view be viable? And only if they click yes there, the selections underneath would show?
Or how would you setup a form like this?

Why would a user need to fill out this form 20 times in a row? Is it because they are actually filling it out for someone else?

A user can be resposible for several places where people can swim / dive and thus fills out the form for each place individually.

When you have a dependency between questions, it's better to show them together, so that users can directly see the effect of their actions.
Sometimes, if you are using a multi-step form, or just show one question at a time, it's better to completely hide the disabled questions. But this doesn't apply if your form might end after just one question.
In order to make the form easy to complete, there are a few things you could do:

Show all questions at once, and disable them based on what the user previously selected. Disable both the question and its answers.

For disabled questions, show a small text below the question mentioning the reason why that question is disabled (for example: "Swimming is required for this question").

Display the options on a single line to reduce the vertical space of the entire form.

Display the options as colorful badges with icons or illustrations, to make them more visually attractive and avoid the perceived effort of completing the form.

Next to each question, show the count of selected answers in order to help users identify the question. You can also mark answered questions with a checkmark, for the same purpose.

Show a progress bar that gets filled with each answered question, to motivate users to complete the form.

Allow users to save their answers as a template, which can later be applied when completing the same form again. You can have a button "Save answers as template" next to "Submit" button. When there is a saved template, you can have a button "Apply answers from template". This would drastically help users that have to complete the same form 20 times.

Show a confetti animation after submitting the form, to give users a pleasant memory from completing the form and make them forget about the effort.



Note: your questions should be short and simple.
1. Is swimming allowed?  
2. Is wearing wetsuit allowed?  
3. Forbidden belongings:  
4. Swimming considerations:  
5. Possible dangers:  


thank you, this helped a lot!

You're welcomed
